# How to populate custom identity resource claim for hybrid flow client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 server with a custom identity resource:

```
new IdentityResource
{
    Name = "custom.profile",
    UserClaims = new[] { "location" }
}
```

This resource is used by the users of an ASP.NET MVC client connecting wiht OIDC hybrid flow and no consent page:

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client.mvc",
                    ClientName = "MVC Core Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                    ...
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "custom.profile"
                    },
```

Login is done manually in `<idsrv>/Login/DoLogin`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoLogin(LoginInputModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.Username == "test.user" && model.Password == "password")
                {
                    Guid userId = new Guid("8da49efb-a1aa-4253-bb7f-56cc6c532b78");

                    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(userId.ToString(), model.Username);

                    if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    return Redirect("~/");
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
```

My question is, how/where do I populate this "`location`" value of the "`custom.profile`" scope for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to implement the `GetProfileDataAsync` method on the `IProfileService` service to add some claims.

So in startup make sure you have something like:

```
identityServerBuilder.Services.AddScoped<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
```

And then in your `ProfileService` class have something like this:

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context) {
    context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim()); //Your claims(s)
}
```

Comment: That's almost correct. You should have a look at the request claim types first. They get passed in as part of the context.

Comment: @leastprivilege: If I'm not mistaken you have to implement IProfileService and call /connect/userinfo endpoint on client (like in OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event) to get custom claims and you can't add custom claims in server side in IdentityServer4 without using extension grants, am I correct?